# INTERVAL vs TIMESTAMP (or similar)

Tags: postgresql

I am wondering: Do I have any advantages when using `INTERVAL` instead of using to `TIMESTAMP` attributes `from` and `to`?

I am asking because I am having a table `time_period` that is supposed to be function as an abstract way of storing time interval information on a day and/or hour level:

```
CREATE TABLE time_period (

    -- PRIMARY KEY

    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    -- ATTRIBUTES

    valid_for_days INT NOT NULL,

    day_from TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    day_to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,

    time_from TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    time_to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
```

Would I be better off using `INTERVAL` here?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two timestamps is an interval:

```
select now() - '2015-01-01';
         ?column?         
--------------------------
 370 days 18:45:20.312403
```

You only need two timestamps to have an interval not four.

If you store that as an interval you will lose the timestamp reference.